# Unable to target element using $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(".box1").next().is(".box2")) {
        $(this).css("margin", "0"); 
}
});
```

My `.box1` div has a style of `margin: 50px`.

To summarize, what I want: If a `.box2` div appears after a `.box1` div, then my `.box1` div now has a margin of 0px. I have 10 `.box1` divs and not all `.box1` divs have a `.box2` div appearing after them. I only want the `.box1` divs with a `.box2` div appearing after them to have `margin:0px`. I don't know how to achieve this with my current code using the $(this) keyword. Please help, thank you

Comment: What do you expect `$(this)` to be outside an event handler?

Comment: @Barmar Sorry I forgot to add that. I actually don't want to use an event/click handler. I just want the function to load automatically.

Comment: I know what you want, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't assigned anything to `this`, since the code isn't in an event handler (well, technically `ready` is considered an event in jQuery, but it's not really helpful in this case).

You can use `.each()` to loop over all the elements of a selection, then `this` will be the current element in the iteration.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".box1").each(function() {
        if ($(this).next().is(".box2")) {
            $(this).css("margin", "0"); 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! I just didn't know how to target an element using $(this) with document.ready. I only knew how with a click handler. Thanks for the quick resolve!

Answer (score 4):

Here’s another possible approach, which should have similar performance if there are similar numbers of `.box1` and `.box2`:

```
$(".box2").prev(".box1").css("margin", "0");
```

Comment: Very nice. It's too bad there's no CSS selector for this, then jQuery wouldn't be needed at all.

Comment: How is this different than `.box1 + .box2`?

Comment: @ErikPhilips: It selects the `.box1`s.

Comment: @Ry- A very simplistic way of resolving my issue - thank you!